# C# How to recolor an image with keeping all of its structure

Tags: c#, image, colors, bitmap

I want to programmatically recolor an image as seen below:

[image]

So how can I do that without fully painting the whole image to one solid color?

Comment: You may want to look into ColorMatrix.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest converting the RGB (Red Green Blue) color to a HSB/HSV (Hue Satuation Brightness / Hue Saturation Value) color. Then you can shift the colors by changing the Hue value. Keep Saturation and Value (Brightness) and convert it back to RGB.

You can get the H, S, V values like this:

```
Color color = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
float h = color.GetHue();
float s = color.GetSaturation();
float v = color.GetBrightness();
```

There is no built-in way for the reverse transformation. You can find a C# example here: [Converting HSV to RGB colour using C#](http://www.splinter.com.au/converting-hsv-to-rgb-colour-using-c/). Also, don't forget to copy the alpha component containing the transparency information, if the image has transparent parts.

The hue is measured in degrees, ranging from 0.0f through 360.0f, so would change the hue like this:

```
float delta = 120f; // Arbitrary value in the range 0.0f through 360.0f
h = (h + delta) % 360f;
```

See also: [HSL and HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)

Another excellent article with C# examples: [Manipulating colors in .NET - Part 1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19045/Manipulating-colors-in-NET-Part)

Comment: Hmm ok, but it seems to paint the whole image, so the empty parts get filled with color too. That shouldn't be the case...

Comment: Well that's probably my fault, because I colored every pixel, but is there any way to get all the pixels that are actually used in the image?

Comment: No, black remains black and white remains white. I.e., it does not colorize the image but only shifts existings colors.

Comment: Yeh true, but what I need is, that the program keeps the empty pixels which it doesn't. Instead it makes every pixel black that was empty before.

Comment: Well then check `if (color != Color.Empty) { do the transformation } else { keep empty }` or if you are using transparency, then you must copy the A component to the new color as welll (the `Color` stucture stores ARGB). It depends what you mean by "empty".

Comment: Somehow the method seems to calculate it in the wrong way. Like I tryed to convert it from rgb to hsv and than back to rgb and it returned a slighlty different value than I had before...

Comment: The values might be off by 1. Since R, G and B are stored as `int` the floats have to rounded.

Comment: You could just make sure to preserve alpha on the pixels after the transformation.